# Фоновый слайдер на CSS

Tags: css, слайдер

Уважаемые знатоки, не могу разобраться как происходит смена картинок( по какому принципу) и почему первый круг анимации проходит нормально, а со второго круга, первая картинка показывается не полностью, и не успев исчезнуть быстро появляется вторая. Я нашел статью откуда взял пример такого слайдера, но из описания не смог, и с трудом понимаю по какому принципу высчитываются проценты Opacity для затухания картинки(или анимации).

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.bg:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmC2r.png);
}

.bg:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwE2F.png);
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.0s;
}

.bg:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzoAj.png);
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.0s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="bg ">Yellow</div>
  <div class="bg ">Turquoise</div>
  <div class="bg ">Black</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда я подредактировал ваш вопрос и обеспечил рабочий фрагмент, проблема натурально проявилась сама-собой.

Дело в Copy/Paste опечатке. Для третьей картинки задержка должна быть 8s, а не 4s:

```
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.0s;
```

```css
header {
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.bg:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmC2r.png);
}

.bg:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwE2F.png);
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.0s;
}

.bg:nth-child(3) {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzoAj.png);
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.0s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  16% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  51% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="bg ">Yellow</div>
  <div class="bg ">Turquoise</div>
  <div class="bg ">Black</div>
</header>
```

Comment: спасибо, мне аж стыдно за такое) я думал проблема посерьезней будет